# On opening a Google Sheet, how can I activate the 1st empty cell in column1?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Volunteers sign in for work by scanning a QR code on their ID cards. The scanned data is entered into a Google Sheet. When the sheet is opened each morning, the first volunteer has to remember to click on the first empty cell in column 1, before scanning his ID card.

How can I automate this, so when the sheet is opened the first empty cell in column 1 is activated/selected and ready for the first scan of the day?

I am very inexperienced with script for google apps. I tried modifying code I found online, but it won't run.

```
var sheet
var data

function onOpen(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.DataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) {
    if (data[i][1] === "") {
       break;
    }
  }
  sheet.getrange(i+1, 2).activate();
}
```

The script doesn't run, but returns this error message.

> TypeError: Cannot find function DataRange in object Sheet. (line 9,
>   file "1st Open Cell, Column1"

Comment: It should be `getDataRange()`. However, Cooper's answer will be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I tested and worked as you want. I used getNextDataCell function [1] to find the last cell with data for column A, and then I used offset function [2] to get the next cell in the column A (empty cell).

```
function onOpen(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //Find the last cell with data in that specific column (A in this case)
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange("A1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN);
  //Activate the next cell
  lastCell.offset(1, 0).activate();
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset-columnoffset

Comment: Thanks Andres! This is very close. I had to change "A" to 'A' to make it run. However, it activates the first non-hidden cell in column A, rather than the first empty cell. Any ideas to fix that?

Comment: You mean you want to activate the first hidden empty cell?

Comment: No. Whenever the sheet is opened, the first visible cell below the Column A header is activated, regardless of whether that cell contains data. So if rows 4-20 are hidden, the script activates cell A21. Does it matter that the data is text?

Comment: I just tried your script on another sheet and it works perfectly there. Now looking for differences between the sheets.

Comment: I don't understand. May be if you share an example of the spreadsheet and explain the case, editing the question. Apps Script functions don't take hidden cells into account.

Comment: Andres, thanks for your help. Your script worked perfectly on other spreadsheets, but not on the one where I planned to use it. So, I recreated that spreadsheet from scratch and now the script is working there too.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
  sheet.getRange(1,sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).activate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Cooper. I got the other one working after recreating the sheet. Not sure where the bug was, but everything pointed to that particular sheet. I'll keep a copy of your script in case the problem reappears.